# Partial update of multiple iframes not working

Tags: iframe, xpages

On a XPage (named "xBase") I have two IFrames inside a container (div):

```
<xp:div id="divIFrames">
    <iframe src="xTest.xsp?key=abc" id="iframe0" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="28px" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    <iframe src="xTest.xsp?key=def" id="iframe1" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="28px" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    <xp:label><xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:context.getUrl().toString();}]]></xp:this.value></xp:label>
</xp:div>
```

Both IFrames point to another XPage "xTest" in my database, with different URL parameters. For simplicity, "xTest" contains only a label with the current URL:

```
<xp:label value="#{javascript:context.getUrl().toString()}"></xp:label>
```

However, the **partial update of the container is not working** and a URL parameter is added to "xBase": $$ajaxid=view%3A_id1%3AdivIFrames

This problem only occurs if there are more than 1 iframes with a URL parameter there. For example, it works properly for multiple iframes **without** URL parameter in the src or for a single iframe with URL parameter. Why doesn't it work for 2 or more IFrames with URL parameters? Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

**EDIT**:

**It turned out that not the partial refresh, but setting variables in the sessionScope is not working when there are multiple IFrames on a XPage. As this would not fit to the current question I created a [new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052911/cannot-set-sessionscope-variable-when-multiple-iframes-are-present-on-a-xpage). I'm sorry for the inconvenience!**

Comment: _“However, there is a problem”_ – … that you somehow forgot to __describe.__

Comment: The problem is described in the title: The partial update is not working properly! Still thanks for the tipp. I modified the question and hope it's more clear now.

Comment: "not working properly" isn't a description of a propblem which is of any use. Are we supposed to guess exactly what is going wrong?

Comment: let me clarify: **THE PARTIAL UPDATE IS NOT WORKING IF THERE IS MORE THAN 1 IFRAME WITH A URL PARAMETER IN THE SRC**

Comment: This question is **valid** and I don't understand why was it closed! Neither do I have an answer for it. I cannot reopen it as [it requires at least 3000 reputation with additional condition that at least 5 people must agree to reopen it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question). Anyone out there?

Comment: Happend to me to, if you tag the question wrong like i did (added jsf, to an xpage question) and talked about IBM components in jsf lifecycle i got the answer: dont use IBM components and my question got closed... ..i could say something about people who tag a question as not valid only because they dont understand it but i think my comment would get flaged..

Comment: I think what they're looking for is a definition of what "not working" means... "not working" is assumed; otherwise, you wouldn't be here. :) Does it throw an error? Are the anticipated HTML elements missing from the DOM? Describe what you expected to happen and what happened instead. A specific use case also goes a long way toward identifying if the use of iframes is even appropriate for your objective. What end user requirement was this technique intended to deliver?

Comment: hmm - just a quick thought: have you tried using 2 different xpages instead of the same xpage twice? Would that make any difference?

Comment: and a second thought to go along: following Tim's thoughts: is there a specific reason why you're using iframes here instead of say custom controls or maybe xpage includes? Currently I can't think of a reason why I would use iframes to render xpages coming from the same db source as my main xpage...

Comment: (1) thanks for reopening. i had the feeling that i'm actually too dumb to ask a question. (2) to Lothar Mueller: yes, i tried using 2 different xpages, but i got the same result. (3) as the fileupload-control needs a full refresh, i put it into a xpage and run it in an iframe to prevent a full refresh of the main xpage. sometimes i need more than 1 fileupload and so i need to have more than 1 iframe.

Answer (score 2):

The changed label in *xBase.xsp* indicates that the partial refresh worked correctly. The URL parameter

```
?$$ajaxid=view%3A_id1%3AdivIFrames
```

is added because this is how a partial refresh works: It is an Ajax request to the XPage itself, and the parameter is the id of the element which is refreshed with the request. The label which displays the request URL is inside the refreshed DOM element, that's why you see it.

Because of a caching of the *context.getUrl()* method you will sometimes see the "original" query and sometimes the URL with the Ajax parameters. If you change the example code to...

```
facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getQueryString();
```

... you will see the parameters without any caching.

BTW: I have tested the example code for fun with 1000 IFrames and it is working for me without any problems.

Please give more informations about your environment (Domino Version, Browser etc.)

Comment: thanks for the info about the caching of context.getUrl(). in my case the url parameter is just added when the partial refresh "fails", that's why i thought it mattered. however, as you said that the code was working for you, i did more testing and found out that the problem is not the partial refresh itself, but the submission of the page. i will describe the submission problem in a new question and close this one. i'm truly sorry for the inconvenience.