# Cannot set sessionScope variable when multiple IFrames are present on a XPage

Tags: xpages

I have a XPage ("xBase") containing multiple IFrames, each showing a XPage ("xIFrame") in my database. When clicking on a button in xBase, a sessionScope variable is set and a label showing this variable is partially refreshed (see example code). Displaying the variable this way works fine as long as there are not too many IFrames. In the short demo example below the display only works up to 3 IFrames, but as soon as there are 4 or more present, the sessionScope variable is not set anymore.

I tested the given example in Notes Client 8.5.3, Firefox 13.0.1 and Safari 5.1.7 - with the same result. It does not appear to be a problem with the partial refresh itself because refreshing a label showing the current time works properly. Can anybody please tell me what the problem is?

XPage "**xBase**":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">

<xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.remove("testvar");}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>

<xp:div id="divIFrames">
<iframe src="xIFrame.xsp?para0=abc" id="iframe0" name="iframe0"></iframe>
<iframe src="xIFrame.xsp?para0=def" id="iframe1" name="iframe1"></iframe>
<iframe src="xIFrame.xsp?para0=ghi" id="iframe2" name="iframe2"></iframe>
<iframe src="xIFrame.xsp?para0=jkl" id="iframe3" name="iframe3"></iframe>
<iframe src="xIFrame.xsp?para0=mno" id="iframe4" name="iframe4"></iframe>
</xp:div>
<xp:br/>

<xp:button value="refresh iframes" id="button0">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="divIFrames"></xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
<xp:br/><xp:br/>

<xp:label id="label"><xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:new Date().toUTCString()+": "+sessionScope.containsKey("testvar")}]]></xp:this.value></xp:label>
<xp:br></xp:br>

<xp:button value="set sessionScope / refresh label" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial" refreshId="label">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.put("testvar","STRING");}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>

</xp:view>
```

XPage "**xIFrame**" (just a label showing time and url > simple to ensure it is not causing the problem):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
<xp:label value="#{javascript:new Date().toUTCString()+':'+context.getUrl().toString()}"></xp:label>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Can you try to set *xsp.session.transient=true* in your XSP properties? Does this work?

Comment: i added the line to my db's xsp.properties file, but the problem is still there.

Comment: no, it's not an XPiNC app. it's intended to run in browsers, but up to now it's also working in the notes client.

Comment: Why are you using iframes? There are alternatives such as Include Page (xp:include).

Comment: when using a fileupload control i need to perform a full refresh to upload a file. in order to also make the upload work in a dialog, i put the control in an iframe to avoid the refresh of the main page.

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten: It is a very interesting problem, because the server side event is not executed anymore. There seems to be be a limitation with when performing more requests than four. Julian Buss found something similiar: http://www.juliusbuss.de/web/youatnotes/blog-jb.nsf/dx/need-help-from-xpages-gurus-issue-with-dojo.xhrget-on-the-notes-client.htm But in this case it was a problem doing four multiple xhr-Calls...

Comment: @xpages-noob: Got it, thanks. Just making sure that you have looked at other alternatives.
Sven, interesting indeed

Comment: Does changing #xsp.persistence.tree.maxviews=4 to more than 4 help? I know that Julian Buss tried this too, but still worth a try

Comment: And you could try to set *xsp.persistence.session.maxviews* to more then four. Btw. I don't have athis limitation on some servers. But I cannot see any difference in the configuration to the other ones.

Comment: Please post xsp.properties of the server and your application and give some details about the server (OS, Domino Version etc.)

Comment: i added xsp.persistence.tree.maxviews=16, xsp.persistence.file.maxviews=16 and xsp.persistence.session.maxviews=16 to xsp.properties, but it didn't solve the problem. btw: i'm changing xsp.properties only in the db im working on. normally this should overwrite the default settings from server-wide properties file... or not?

Comment: **IT WORKS NOW**: adding the 3 parameters above didn't work before, but now i CLEANED the project and suddenly it does. i'll check which minimal set of parameters is needed to make it work and write an answer afterwards. Sven Hasselbach and Per Henrik Lausten: thanks very much for your help. i've been struggling with this problem for quite a while and i'm ultra happy it seems to work now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem can be solved by adding

> xsp.persistence.tree.maxviews=16

to your database's **xsp.properties** file and afterwards cleaning the project. The value of 16 is arbitrary, just make sure it's higher than the number of IFrames you plan to use.

*All the credit is due to Sven Hasselbach and Per Henrik Lausten who provided this solution.*